# Updating react-admin version, fails to read route returned from Cognito hosted ui

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-admin

Updating from react admin 3.9 to 4.10.5, when i login via cognito hosted ui, the redirect back to my site :

`http://localhost:3080/#id_token=eyJra...`

I get a blank page, and in console I get the following warning:

`history.ts:487 No routes matched location "id_token=ey..`

This worked before the upgrade, why does react admin new version mistake auth fragment for a route ?

As per my understanding I have an AuthProvider that should get this URL before react-admin checks route, this authProvider I have stores token and strips the fragment from the URL, but it is not called when the token is in fragment (only on regular routes)